# Los dos números mas grandes de 10 números

Tags: java

Hace 2 horas que estoy con este ejercicio, que no puedo resolver. Mi objetivo es que de 10 números, los 2 mas grandes se impriman en consola. Probando muchas combinaciones funciona, pero cuando elijo números altos, el segundo número más grande falla en el resultado, y no es el correcto.

La combinación que estoy eligiendo para analizarlo es la siguiente:

```
9000
9001
8900
9005
9003
10000
10025
10030
10125
10200
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Porque el resultado en la consola es:

```
10200 (correcto)
9003 (incorrecto)
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Obs: No estoy utilizando ni `array` ni bucles `for`. Solo un `while` con `if .. else` anidados.

Muchas gracias!

```
public class DosNumerosMasGrandes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int contadorNumerosGrandes=1;
        int ingresadoNumero=0;
        int mayorNumero=0;
        int segundoMayor=0;
        int menorNumero;

        while(contadorNumerosGrandes<=10) {
            Scanner entradaNumero=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ingrese la entrada numero: " + contadorNumerosGrandes);         
            ingresadoNumero=entradaNumero.nextInt();

            //CUANDO SE INGRESA EL PRIMER NUMERO
            if(contadorNumerosGrandes==1)   mayorNumero=ingresadoNumero; 
            //CUANDO SE INGRESA EL SEGUNDO NUMERO
            else if(contadorNumerosGrandes==2) {
                if(ingresadoNumero>mayorNumero) mayorNumero=ingresadoNumero;
                else if (ingresadoNumero<mayorNumero) segundoMayor=ingresadoNumero;
            }
            //CUANDO SE INGRESAN EL RESTO DE LOS NUMEROS
            else if(contadorNumerosGrandes>=3){
                if(ingresadoNumero>mayorNumero) mayorNumero=ingresadoNumero;
                else if(ingresadoNumero<mayorNumero) {
                    if(ingresadoNumero>segundoMayor) segundoMayor=ingresadoNumero;
                }
            }
            contadorNumerosGrandes++;
        }
        System.out.println(mayorNumero);
        System.out.println(segundoMayor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gonzalo, hice una edición a mi respuesta, debido a un comentario de @Alberto, que encontró que efectivamente había todavía un caso en que no se comportaba correctamente. Te lo comento para que la revises. Un saludo.

Comment: Te agradezco tu respuesta! Gracias. Voy a revisar el codigo

Comment: @jachguate hola! Como estas? He revisado el código, pero he notado que por ejemplo no funciona con numeros negativos! (secuencia -10, -20, -30). Hace 2 horas estoy con el codigo y pense que era dificil, pero a mi me mato esto :(

Comment: Hola @Gonzalo, todo bien, no funciona con negativos porque las variables se inicializan con `0`. Para que funcione con negativos, habría que inicializarlas con `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Un saludo.

Comment: Perfecto @jachguate! Lo voy a intentar! Saludos y muy amable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DosNumerosMasGrandes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int contadorNumerosGrandes=1;
    int ingresadoNumero=0;
    //para que también funcione con números negativos:
    int mayorNumero  =   Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int segundoMayor =   Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int menorNumero  =   Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    while(contadorNumerosGrandes<=10) {
        Scanner entradaNumero=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese la entrada numero: " + contadorNumerosGrandes);         
        ingresadoNumero=entradaNumero.nextInt();
        //aquí validas si el número ingresado es mayor
        //si es mayor lo actualizas y mandas el mayor anterior al segundo
        if (ingresadoNumero > mayorNumero) {
           segundoMayor = mayorNumero;
           mayorNumero = ingresadoNumero;
        }
        //aquí validas si el número ingresado es mayor que el segundo
        //de ser así lo sustituyes.
        else if (ingresadoNumero > segundoMayor) {
            segundoMayor = ingresadoNumero;
        }
        //aquí validas si el ingresado es menor que el menor anterior
        //de ser así lo sustituyes.
        if (ingresadoNumero < menorNumero) {
           menorNumero = ingresadoNumero;
        }
        contadorNumerosGrandes++;
    }
    System.out.println(mayorNumero);
    System.out.println(segundoMayor);
    System.out.println(menorNumero);
}
}
```

Comment: sólo código sin explicar los cambios no sirve de mucho, por favor edita respuesta para que tenga sentido

Comment: Este codigo esta funcionando muy bien! Ahora voy a estar 2 horas mas tratando de entenderlo. Gracias @AlbertoLopez

Comment: Hola @AlbertoLopez, como estas? Tu codigo funciona de maravilla, incluso estuve unos 10 minutos tratando de entenderlo. Ahora mi pregunta es, que para mi, seria valioso saberlo, como se te ocurrio, ya que es un codigo simple, pero su funcionalidad es compleja. Se que mi pregunta es muy de iniciado, porque lo soy, pero necesito saber que sucedio en tu mente para poder ajustar mis tuercas y poder pensar mas como programador. He realizado algunas aplicaciones, pero esta a pensar de su sencillez me rompio la cabeza. De verdad te lo agradeceria. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Gonzalo. El algoritmo que necesitabas para este ejemplo es común, en el sentido que es usual que requieras obtener los mayores o menores de una lista, u ordenarlos, etc. Como es un requerimiento hasta cierto punto usual, es un código que lo he usado muchas veces. Lo que pasó por mi mente cuando vi tu pregunta es que "yo sé como hacerlo porque lo he hecho muchas veces".  Hay veces que tienes que inventar un código, y hay veces que solo tienes que recordarlo. Pero es importante entenderlo. Para un programador 10 minutos no es nada, 1 semana no es nada. Saludos.

Comment: Muy sabia tu respuesta, gracias por ayudarme a ser un programador de a poco! Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu fallo no tiene nada que ver con que sean números grandes o pequeños, sino con el orden en que se introducen los números.

Puedes simplificar mucho la lógica, en realidad necesitas un `if/else/if`. Me explico:

Si lo reflexionas bien, debes identificar cuando el número ingresado sea mayor que el que está almacenado en la variable `mayorNumero`. En ese caso, el que está en `mayorNumero` se convierte automáticamente en el `segundoMayor`. Si no lo es, cabe la posibilidad que el ingresado aún sea mayor que el `segundoMayor`, lo que evaluamos en el `else if`, y en ese caso asignamos ese valor a la variable.

Este programa produce la salida correcta con la secuencia que propones:

```
public class DosNumerosMasGrandes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int contadorNumerosGrandes = 1;
        int ingresadoNumero = 0;
        int mayorNumero = 0;
        int segundoMayor = 0;

        while(contadorNumerosGrandes<=10) {
            Scanner entradaNumero=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ingrese la entrada numero: " + contadorNumerosGrandes);         
            ingresadoNumero = entradaNumero.nextInt();
            if (ingresadoNumero > mayorNumero) {
              segundoMayor = mayorNumero;
              mayorNumero = ingresadoNumero;
            } else if (ingresadoNumero > segundoMayor) {
              segundoMayor = ingresadoNumero;
            }
            contadorNumerosGrandes++;
        }
        System.out.println("Resultado");
        System.out.println("Mayor: " + mayorNumero);
        System.out.println("Segundo: " + segundoMayor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Increible, en 3 lineas resolviste todo. Cuando llegare a ese nivel? Son años de programar, no?

Comment: jajaja, no te atrevas a llamarme viejo, jajaja. :D. Si te sirvió la pregunta, ¿sabes [qué hacer cuando te responden](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Un saludo.

Comment: creo que el algoritmo es incorrecto. Si hay números iguales no los considera y no ordena el segundo mas que en algunos casos.

Comment: @Alberto, la pregunta no especifica que deba realizarse nada específico si hay números iguales. Sobre el que no ordena el segundo, en realidad, no comprendo lo que quieres decir, pues no hay nada también en la pregunta acerca de ordenar nada, lo que se requiere es dar los dos números más grandes y considero que el programa cumple con ese requerimiento.

Comment: @jachguate, ingresa a tu algoritmo esta secuencia 10, 30, 20. Según yo te va arrojar que los 2 números mayores son 30 y 10. Cuando debería arrojar 30 y 20. Por lo que según yo, no te da los dos números más grandes. Que es el objetivo de la clase, en mi opinión.

Comment: @Alberto, tienes toda la razón, hice ya la corrección a la respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias a ambos! Mucho mas claro ahora

Answer (score 0):

Gonzalo. La duda que tienes es respecto a métodos de ordenamiento. Te recomiendo resolverlo con algún método de burbuja o inserción para cuestiones de resolver el problema actual y posteriormente puedas realizar un ejercicio con métodos de ordenamiento más complejos.

Creo que tu programa podría quedar algo similar a lo siguiente si optas por leer los 10 números primero y después los ordenas con el método de inserción.

```
 int[] arreglo = new int[10];
 while(contadorNumerosGrandes<10) {
            Scanner entradaNumero=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ingrese la entrada numero: " + contadorNumerosGrandes+1);         
            ingresadoNumero=entradaNumero.nextInt();
    }


  for (int i=1; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
     int aux = vector[i];
     int j;
     for (j=i-1; j > =0 && arreglo[j] > aux; j--){
          arreglo[j+1] = arreglo[j];
      }
     arreglo[j+1] = aux;
  }
```

El siguiente es un enlace del que puedes leer un poco más sobre este tema. Espero te resulte útil
https://enrrike87.blogspot.com/2011/06/metodos-de-ordenamiento-java_21.html

Comment: Gracias Pak! Muy interesando lo que me has comentado acerca de estos metodos, por lo que veo, son como patrones!